# c program interpreting a bracket within a function parameter as a second function

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to write this program in c to run a file within program files but when I write the function

```
system("users/user/program files (x86).....")
```

it interprets the `(` in `(x86)` as a second function.

Is there some symbol I can put before the bracket so that it takes it literally?

Answer (score 3):

Unlike bash or other sane shells, windows shell doesn't allow `\` escape characters (If there is another character, I don't know of it), but one thing you can do is to put everything that is supposed to be one item in `"`:

```
system("\"program that has space and other weird characters\" \"arg1\" \"arg2\"");
```

Quoting in shell prevents the shell itself from trying to understand what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is separating the command line on spaces.  Try quoting it:

```
system("\"users/user/program files (x86)...\" [arguments]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the shell not liking the parentheses.  Try this:

```
system("users/user/program files '(x86)'.....")
```

Comment: I tried that but then it just takes "users/user/program files '" as the name of a function

Comment: @user1898185: How do you know it is taking it as a function?  What error are you seeing?